# How do I display rows individually at a set interval?

Tags: php, javascript, css

Here is the issue .... I have a PHP program reading and displaying the contents (4 text fields) of a MySQL database. These records are displayed sequentially down the page. What I hope to do is read a record and display the text, have a little timer to pause and then display the next record in the same location on the page. Like a slide show of text.

If I use the CSS position command the text is positioned in the same place but it just writes right over the previous record.  Is there a way to clear/delete content at a specific position on a page ....  or some other way of doing this?

Comment: Could you post the code you have so far

Answer (score 1):

If your using a library like jQuery to do your JavaScript dirty work, then I would suggest something to the extent of.

```
<style type="text/css">
    ul {
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        overflow:hidden;
        border:#000 1px solid;
    }
    ul li{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        list-style:none;
        width:300px;
        height:300px;
        display:none;
    }
    .active{
        display:block;
    }
</style>

<ul>
   <li class="active">1 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </li>
   <li>2 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </li>
   <li>3 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </li>
   <li>4 Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum. </li>
</ul>​​​​​​​​​​​​​

<script type="text/javascript">
​setInterval(function()
{
   if($('ul li[class="active"]').is(':last-child'))
   {
       $('ul li[class="active"]').removeClass('active');
       $('ul li:first').addClass('active')
   }   
   else
   {
       $('ul li[class="active"]').removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
   }
},5000);
​</script>
```

Where the Ipsum text can be your echoed out results from the query, and you can just place this whole unordered list into your div, you'll just need to tweak sizes accordingly to match your needs.

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BsREB/)

Answer (score 0):

You want the display properties; specifically, display:none and display:block.  Start with the first row having display:block and the rest having display:none, then when the timer advances, switch the first to display:none and the second to display:block.

You probably want to handle this purely through a class.  Set all of the rows to display:none in CSS, then have a single row at a time use an "active" class or something similar which has display:block.